# HTML links with a subdir as a root

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have this simple structure:

```
/
|_index.html
|_includes.html
|_/path/to/page.html
|_/another/path/to/something.html
```

I want to include the same part of the code (read: scripts) into every page. I'm creating `includes.html` in the root with my scripts:

```
<head th:fragment="head-section">
<script th:src="@{/js/site.js}"></script>
</head>
```

Next, in every page I'm including this:

```
<head th:include="includes :: head-section"></head>
```

And everything seems fine untill my site is in the root folder. But then, suddenly I decide to deploy my site for exmaple with a tomcat in his `example` subdir. New address is: `http://localhost/example/...`. `Example` is my new root and links become broken because they are looking into the `'/'`. The question is - is it possible for me to build such links (dependencies) once and don't touch them in the future in such cases?
I am using `Spring + Thymeleaf` in my project but I don't think that it matters.

Comment: The javascript/html answer is that you would need to specify the subdirectory in the path. If you don't know the subdirectory, then you'll want to use your application server to fill in the subdirectory for you.  I.e. I think it does matter that you're using Spring + Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:
I am sorry, I've made some strange mistake because it is correct in example. 
From [thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) documentation:

> **Context-relative URLs**
>
> The most used type of URLs are context-relative ones. These are URLs which are supposed to be relative to the web application root once it is installed on the server. For example, if we deploy a myapp.war file into a Tomcat server, our application will probably be accessible as http://localhost:8080/myapp, and myapp will be the context name.

Context-relative URLs start with /:

```
<a th:href="@{/order/list}">
```

If our app is installed at http://localhost:8080/myapp, this URL will output:

```
<a href="/myapp/order/list">
```